# Как проверить, существует ли каталог на Яндекс.Диске

Tags: php

Нормально подключился к приложению через yandex-php-library, могу создавать каталоги, файлы и т. д. Но как можно проверить, существует ли уже такая папка, которую я хочу создать. При использовании `$disk->createDirectory('Папка');` (при том, что она уже существует) php выдаёт фатальную ошибку и простым If'ом или try catch никак не получается проверить.

Comment: Судя по коду, createDirectory выкинет DiskRequestException, который по идее должен успешно перехватываться catch'ем. Что-то у вас в php сломано, видимо

Comment: Блин, catch действительно работает, но почему, когда catch срабатывает и я пишу просто echo "Поймано исключение" после этого сообщение ниже всё равно появляется эта фатальная ошибка? Нужно отключать display_error?
+ ещё ДО catch появляется warning:

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/vertical/app/yandex-php-library_master.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 67